# Change color of Circles on D3 Packing

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to change the color of individual nodes in the circle packing visualization.  The colors are in each "D" object as color.  When I try and use the fill attribute and just return d.color only the text changes and not the actual node itself.  Specific nodes have different colors.

```
circle {
fill: blue;
fill-opacity: .25;
stroke: #0066FF;
stroke-width: 1px;
}

.leaf circle {
 fill: yellow;
 fill-opacity: 1;
 }

 var node = svg.datum(root).selectAll(".node")
  .data(pack.nodes)
.enter().append("g")
  .attr("fill", function(d) {return d.color})
  //.attr("class", function(d) { return d.children ? "node" : "leaf node"; })
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

First, you need to set it on the `circle` and not the `g` element.

Second, the CSS fill property in your base style will then take precedence over the attribute fill.  So use:

```
node.append("circle")
  .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
  .style('fill', function(d) {return d.color});
```

Comment: great to change the color of the text would it just be:  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name + (d.children ? "" : ": " + format(d.size)); })
      .style("color", function(d){return "red"});

Comment: @Ben, SVG `text` uses fill as well: `.style('fill', 'red')`, of course if you want them all red, I'd set it globally, `<style> .node text{ fill: red; } </style>`